# Where i can get a list of most popular browsed servers domains by users of a specific country?

Tags: data-request

I'm pretty sure that some net index study like this was already carried out.

I would like to obtain a list of top 50-100 most frequently accessed locations by users of a specific country.

An example:

Let's say I'm interested in users coming from germany. Wich are the most popular browsing locations by users coming from "germany"?

German users connect mostly on servers in this order:

```
1) us - usa servers (facebook, linkedin, google, ..) 65% of requests
2) de - germany servers (for all .de websites locations) 30% of requests
3) gb - uk servers 2% of requests
4) nl - netherlands servers 1% of requests
5) fr - france servers 0.5% of requests
6) it - italian servers 0.3% of requests
8) cn - china servers 0.01% of requests
9) jp - japan servers 0.004% of requests
10) ca - canada servers 0.004% of requests
11) kr - korea servers 0.001% of requests
...
...
...
49) ar - argentina servers 0.0005% of requests
50) br - brazil servers 0.00001% of requests
```

This way i know for example that generally users coming from Germany are not really interested in servers or domains present in Brazil